# Oracle migration to SQL Server: SQL Server Equivalent to Oracle Global variables

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, oracle-11g-r2, ssma

I am working in a Oracle 11g database migration to SQL Server 2012, I did the migration using SSMA v5.3 and all works fine.
However, I did re-write code in some objects like triggers and stored procedures because the SSMA did a standard migration.

But my questions is about this: 
The Oracle Db have some packages that use global variables like this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package OPS_TRACKING.pkg_trade_data as

-- packaged variable to be used by triggers not to execute during
-- archival and resoring process of the trade data
archive_restore_flag  varchar2(1) := 'N';
procedure p_archive_trade_data( p_trade_id    number );
```

In my case this global variable is called for some triggers like it:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "OPS_TRACKING"."TG_TRADE_GROUP_AER_DI" 
after insert or delete on ops_tracking.trade_group
for each row
declare
  v_id  number;
  v_trade_id number;
begin
   If pkg_trade_data.archive_restore_flag = 'N' Then

      if inserting then
         v_trade_id := :new.trade_id;
      else
         v_trade_id := :old.trade_id;
      end if;

      select id into v_id from ops_tracking.trade_summary
      where trade_id = v_trade_id
      for update nowait;

      update ops_tracking.trade_summary
         set transaction_seq=ops_tracking.seq_trade_summary_transaction.nextval
            ,last_update_timestamp_gmt = sysdate
       where trade_id = v_trade_id;

   End If; -- archive_restore_flag
end tg_trade_group_aer_di;
/
```

As you can see in this `trigger` the global variable
`(pkg_trade_data.archive_restore_flag = 'N')` is used for take a decision and based in their value the oracle trigger execute the action.

I would like to know which is the equivalent or which are my options to migrate this code to SQL 2012.

I appreciate your comments and advice's.

Comment: Package variables are not global, they persist for the duration of a session. In SQLServer you have similar behaviour (in your case) with  ` CONTEXT_INFO ` - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189252(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Alternatively you can use a local temporary table to store the value, as it has a similar lifecycle.

Comment: But using temporary table i will need the application code create the temp table for get a value or how you think I can save the value in the temp table for use it in the trigger. Thanks

Comment: Befor the trigger is created the temp table has to be created. Where is the problem?

Comment: @a1ex07 I think one should avoid CONTEXT_INFO. there is only one CONTEXT_INFO. So the conept cannot be extended to a second package variable. If a script uses CONTEXT_VARIABLE the behaviour of the trigger will be influenced.

Comment: Well, I will try your advice miracle173 maybe the temp table is my solution to get the value and validate if is necessary perform the action within the trigger

Comment: @miracle173 : I agree with your argument that there is only one `CONTEXT_INFO` (however, I don't see anything in the question that implies presence of another package variable)... The trigger will be influenced in any case because it relies on an object that is supposedly created by some external piece of code...

Comment: @a1ex07 Well I have another trigger that use this variable I mean above and also use another global variable from other package. I am not sure if about it your try to mean

Comment: @jmonterohn : Then context_info won't work... As miracle173 said, temp table should do the job with some restrictions ( you will very likely end up with attribute-value  table thus leaving type casting to the callee )